# How can I add HTML5 support to Vim without plugins?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, html5

I'm using OS X, but I don't think that matters.

By default, both MacVim and [terminal] Vim handle auto-indentation of HTML 4.0 elements, but any HTML5 elements, such as `<header>` and `<footer>`, don't trigger the auto-indentation. They're also not syntax-highlighted.

How can I add let Vim recognize HTML5 elements, or better yet, make Vim recognize *any* element instead of only pre-configured ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without plugin, you can locate the html syntax file and add the html5 elements. But other people have already done the work for you, [I think](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=html5&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search).

Comment: I wasn't able to find the existing syntax file, but the one you linked to worked well. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. The default HTML syntax file can be found in `/usr/share/vim`. For MacVim it's located inside of the app bundle.